# Pandas: Treating a Series as a step-function during add()?

Tags: pandas, time-series

When two time series with non-identical indexes are added, index values which are not common to both time series are created and assigned NaN.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

ts1 = pd.Series([1, 2], index=[datetime(2011,1,2), datetime(2011,1,3)])
ts2 = pd.Series([3, 4], index=[datetime(2011,1,3), datetime(2011,1,4)])

ts1.add(ts2)
  2011-01-02    NaN
  2011-01-03    5.0
  2011-01-04    NaN
  dtype: float64
```

How can I add two series such that a missing datetime point is assigned the value of the immediately preceding datetime value?  (treating the two series as step-wise functions)

For example, I would like to get this results:

```
ts1.add(ts2)
  2011-01-02    NaN     # ts2 has no prior value for this date, so still NaN
  2011-01-03    5.0     #
  2011-01-04    6.0     # ts1 carries over the value 2 from 2011-01-03
  dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reindex both Series with the union of their indices, you can use the `ffill` method to fill missing values with the previous ones.

```
union = ts1.index.union(ts2.index)
ts1.reindex(union, method='ffill').add(ts2.reindex(union, method='ffill'))
```

yields

```
2011-01-02    NaN
2011-01-03    5.0
2011-01-04    6.0
dtype: float64
```